# Room поле дата в БД

Tags: android, sqlite

Хотелось бы узнать как в БД SQLite используя Room хранить поле типа Date и поле типа Time?

Пишу приложение, куда можно будет добавлять доходы и расходы, а также покупки. Так вот при добавлении таких данных нужно в БД в отдельные поля записывать дату и время. А затем делать выборки типа сколько и на какую сумму было сделано покупок за день, неделю и т.д.

Все это хочу реализовать используя Room.

Comment: И прямо в гугеле нет ничего про это?

Comment: пишут что в текстовом или вещественном типе. В некоторых местах пишут что в long хранить. Как правильнее всего?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос: Что такое `Room`? Какая у вас схема таблицы? Чего хотите в итоге, хотя бы приблизительно.

Comment: У SQLite нет специального формата для хранения времени, поэтому хранят его в виде форматированной строки, целого (`millis`, `unix epoch`) или вещественного (как в Exel) числа. Какой именно формат хранения вам удобнее, тот и используйте. Поле в Entity тоже можете сделать любого удобного вам типа и не обязательно того же, что поле в БД - этот нюанс решают конвертером (подробнее: [startandroid.ru: Урок 11. Room. Type converter](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/27-course/architecture-components/539-urok-11-room-type-converter.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Room - обертка для SQLite. SQLite не имеет типа для хранения даты, но имеет некоторые функции для обработки дат, записанных как числа или текст.

Вариант первый: целочисленные(аки long) хранит число миллисекунд, прошедших с 00:00 01.01.1970(гуглить timestamp). В этом же формате хранят даты родные для Java классы Time, Date и Calendar, так же обрабатывает время библиотека йода и много где еще. Лично я в любых бд время сохраняю именно так, удобно считать временные отрезки, проверять попадания в рэнж или пересечения рэнжов и т.д. и т.п. Перевести в человеческий вид тоже нетрудно

Второй вариант: хранить как вещественное число. Целая часть числа - число дней, прошедших с 01.01.1900, дробная часть позволяет получить время

Третий вариант: строка в формате "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS.sss". Обычно используется для записи даты, с которой никогда никаких операций кроме вывода не происходит, в т.ч. не сравнивается с другими датами

Со всеми тремя способами работают родные SQLite функции для преобразований и сравнений, вопрос производительности именно внутри базы весьма сложный и спорный. Выбирать какой именно использовать нужно исходя из того, что вы будете делать с датами вне базы. Если только показывать - можно записывать строкой, если сортировать по дате и выбирать из списка по рэнжу - timestamp в помощь. Вещественным числом хранить удобно в некоторых задачках в духе школьных олимпиад по программированию, но не думаю что найдется задача где удобно такой формат писать в бд

Comment: Поняла, спасибо.