# Хранение даты в Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Хочу написать небольшое приложение, которое будет работать с БД.. В одной из таблиц будет поле createdate, куда будет записываться дата выбранная в приложении. Причем дата будет выбираться отдельно, а время отдельно (затем будут отчеты по датам строиться). Как нужно хранить дату в самой БД? строковый тип лучше или integer?

Comment: TIMESTAMP - 4 байта 
Строка - много больше

Comment: т.е. я могу хранить в БД в числовом виде? сделать поле типа integer.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/602048/177345

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Room поле дата в БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021814/room-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал хранить в строке в формате ISO. При таком подходе сохраняется часовой пояс и легко можно сконвертировать эту дату в произвольный формат.

Comment: sqlite понимает только timestring вида YYYY-MM-DD [HH:MM:SS] и unix timestamp, все прочие ISO-форматы (стандарт предлагает множество вариантов) можно будет вывести как строку, но нельзя сделать выборку из базы, например, по диапазону дат. считывать же из БД строку, затем конвертировать средствами Java в дату и с этим работать по диапазону - вариант для мазохистов